# Http Post Exception at OutputStream

Tags: java, c#, android, http-post

I'm trying to fire an http post request and my problem is that I'm getting an Exception at `DataOutputStream`, i think i know where but i dont know why.

the code is

```
public string sendFileToServer(string filename, string targetUrl)
    {
        string response = "error";
        Log.Error("Image filename", filename);
        Log.Info("url", targetUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        // DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        string pathToOurFile = filename;
        string urlServer = targetUrl;
        string lineEnd = "\r\n";
        string twoHyphens = "--";
        string boundary = "*****";
        Java.Text.DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH:mm:ss");

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.DoInput = true;
            connection.DoOutput = true;
            connection.UseCaches = false;
            connection.SetChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            // Enable POST method
            connection.RequestMethod = "POST";

            connection.SetRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.SetRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.OutputStream);
            outputStream.WriteBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            string connstr = null;
            connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd;
            Log.Info("Connstr", connstr);

            outputStream.WriteBytes(connstr);
            outputStream.WriteBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.Available();
            bufferSize = Java.Lang.Math.Min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Log.Error("Image length", bytesAvailable + "");
            try
            {
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
                    {
                        e.PrintStackTrace();
                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
                        return response;
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.Available();
                    bufferSize = Java.Lang.Math.Min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
                response = "error";
                return response;
            }
            outputStream.WriteBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.WriteBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = (int)connection.ResponseCode;
            string serverResponseMessage = connection.ResponseMessage;
            Log.Info("Server Response Code ", "" + serverResponseCode);
            Log.Info("Server Response Message", serverResponseMessage);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200)
            {
                response = "true";
            }

            string CDate = null;
            Date serverTime = new Date(connection.Date);
            try
            {
                CDate = df.Format(serverTime);
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
                Log.Error("Date Exception", e.Message + " Parse Exception");
            }
            Log.Info("Server Response Time", CDate + "");

            filename = CDate
                    + filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("."),
                            filename.Length);
            Log.Info("File Name in Server : ", filename);

            fileInputStream.Close();
            outputStream.Flush();
            outputStream.Close();
            outputStream = null;
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
        {
            // Exception handling
            response = "error";
            Log.Error("Send file Exception", ex.Message + "");
            ex.PrintStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

here's the full stack trace printed at the exception:

```
    05-29 01:49:10.059 W/System.err(22768): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1108)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:133)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:118)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:849)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14279)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 01:49:10.450 W/System.err(22768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
05-29 01:49:10.460 W/System.err(22768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
05-29 01:49:10.460 W/System.err(22768):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tested the url and there's no issue with it as I'm using it elsewhere in my code. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: It's because you do that in Activity's main thread, write it async in new thread

Comment: I made the  sendFileToServer method async but still same issue

Comment: Impossible. You will not have a NetworkOnMainThreadException then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception? Please give better info. You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` and you have not googled for it otherwise you would have known that the solution is to put network code in an AsyncTask or thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpConnection {
    public String readUrl(String mapsApiDirectionsUrl) throws Exception {
        String data = "";
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream iStream = null;
        InputStreamReader iStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try{
            url = new URL(mapsApiDirectionsUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "PPT");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            writer = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("POST DATA HERE");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            iStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
            br = new BufferedReader(iStreamReader);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();

            return data;
        } finally {
            br.close();
            iStreamReader.close();
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpConnection {
    public String readUrl(String Url) throws Exception {
        String data = "";
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();


        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream iStream = null;
        InputStreamReader iStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try{
            // create server connection using URL path
            url = new URL(Url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "PPT");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            // post data to server using POST method not GET
            writer = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("POST DATA HERE");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            // this get all data that server send to you, the response data
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            iStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
            br = new BufferedReader(iStreamReader);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();

            return data;
        } finally {
            // all connections are closed
            br.close();
            iStreamReader.close();
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

}
```